# Irreducibility of the linear equations variety $Ay=c$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $A\in k^{n^2}, y \in k^n$ and the variety $V\subset k^{n^2 + n}$ generated by equations $Ay=c$ with polynomials in $k[a_{11}, \ldots, a_{nn}, y_1, \ldots, y_n]$ and $c\in k^n$ a fixed vector. Prove that $V$ is irreducible.

My approach until now has been to consider the subset $V_1 \subset V$ where $|A| \neq 0$ which gives the rational parametrization $y = A^{-1}c$, but I'm stuck on proving that its closure $\overline{V_1}=V$. Certainly, $V_1 \neq V$ as the complement $Ay=c$ with $|A| = 0$ is not null in general.

Is there a way to prove that $\overline{V_1}=V$? Also, what other approach would lead to the irreducibility of $V$?

Answer (score 1):

This is true if $ c \neq 0 $ and it follows by the Jacobian criterion: I'll use variables $ x_{ij} $ for the matrix entries and then the equations are $ \sum_{j = 1}^n x_{ij} y_j = c_i $ for each $ i = 1, 2, \ldots , n $. The Jacobian matrix is in the form $ [B_1 | B_2 | \cdots | B_n | x_{ij} ] $ where $ B_k $ is the matrix which has zero entries everywhere except the $ k $-th row, which is $ (y_1, \cdots , y_n) $. Let $ A = (a_{ij}) $ and $ v = (v_k) $ be a (closed) point on this affine scheme $
V $. Since $ c \neq 0 $, there is an index $ l $ such that $ v_l \neq 0 $ so the Jacobian has full rank. So the local rings at closed points of $ V $ are regular, hence $ V $ is regular. A regular local ring is a domain, so $ V $ has all local rings integral domains. But $ V $ has an open subset $ D(Det(x_{ij})) $ mapping isomorphically to its image in $ \mathbb{A}^{n^2} $, which is irreducible, so $ V $ is irreducible as well.

This fails for $ c = 0 $ as for $ n=1$, the single equation is $ xy = 0 $, not irreducible. I don't know what happens if $ c=0 $ and $ n > 1 $.

Comment: You are using that a non-singular variety which is birrational to an irreducible variety is itself irrational. Is this trivial or am I missing something? Good answer btw

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez no, you're not missing anything because I realize that exact step of my argument is incomplete and I don't know how to salvage it, sorry. I'll just leave it up there so that someone else can correct it.

Comment: @CraniumClamp thanks for the answer. I have several questions related to your solution. I've not studied schemes, so I've been trying to refrain your answer in more basic terms. What is $D(Det(x_{ij}))$, non-invertible matrices? How $V$ having all local rings integral domains implies irreducibility when there is a birrational map between an open subset and an affine space?

Comment: @CraniumClamp probably smoothness is enough without using birrationality, please correct me if I'm wrong. Supposing $V$ is reducible, there exists $W\subsetneq V$ such that $V \setminus W$ is not Zariski dense in $V$, therefore we obtain a decomposition $V = W \cup \overline{V \setminus W}$ of non-disjoint proper closed sets. But smoothness implies that any intersection of irreducible components of $V$ is null which is contradictory with the decomposition found before. I know smoothness and connectedness implies irreducibility but I've never seen smoothness alone as sufficient.

Comment: @valerdi the problem is that the intersection might be empty. V is certainly Noetherian and hence, has finitely many irreducible components, each of which are smooth. Now any two of them cannot intersect. (otherwise a point of intersection will not be a non-singular point.) In other words, it might happen that V is V_1 disjoint union V_2 for smooth varieties V_1, V_2.

Comment: @CraniumClamp i unterstood your explanation, using the same line of thought i think we can arrive to the flaw in your answer. A counterexample to your proof is the variety $V = \mathbf{V}((x^2 - y + 1)(x^2 - y - 1))$ in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$, it is smooth and has an open subset $\mathbf{V}(x^2 - y + 1)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Nevertheless, V is reducible.

Comment: I cannot edit my previous comment. I had an error in the counterexample because in $\mathbb{C}^2$ the subset $\mathbf{V}(x^2 - y + 1)$ is not open. Instead, we can use $\mathbf{V}((x^2-y)(x^2-y+1))$.